# Stack Overflow account auto logout

Tags: support

Last few days my Stack Overflow account has auto logout.

Yesterday I have visited the Stack Overflow site and not logged out my account but today opening the site my account has logged out.

Anything new rule or logic introduced in Stack Overflow?

Comment: What browser etc are you using?

Comment: @MartinSmith Browser Version: Mozilla Firefox 35.0.1